# Patient Days calculcation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to write a query to calculate patient days. My source table has VisitID, AdmitDateTime, and DischargeDateTime. A patient day is defined as a patient is in a bed at midnight. So for example, if there were 5 patients admitted on 2016-01-01 and no other patients were in the hospital from before then Patient Days would equal 5 for 2016-01-02.

I would like to display the results with the columns being date and count. I thought about building a calendar table with a CTE but I'm unsure of what the join should be to my source table. If there are no patients in a bed for a certain day I would want the count to be 0. I'm fairly new to SQL any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what is the problem with your solution? Please read [ask] in [help]. Showing some effort highly increases our will to help.

Comment: Typically, you would handle the logic of 'missing' days in application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry would you? I've come across this kind of problem (where you have records which represent events with dates and some dates have no events, but you want to return a count for each day - even those with a count of zero) a few times in the past and have usually found it is solved in the reporting layer, rather than the application layer?

Comment: There are a few suggestions on this similar (I think) question: [How do I include empty rows in a single GROUP BY DAY(date_field) SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592983/how-do-i-include-empty-rows-in-a-single-group-by-daydate-field-sql-query), or this one: [How to return empty groups in SQL GROUP BY clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980678/how-to-return-empty-groups-in-sql-group-by-clause).

Comment: In fact, just Googling for `sql query include empty groups` returns plenty of results (both from SE and elsewhere) which should allow you to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a Calendar table, but if that's not an option for you then here's a solution using a recursive CTE to build your master date list.

Please be aware that this won't work if your overall date-range is more than 100 days due to limitation with cte recursion. (Again. Try and use a calendar table it will be far more efficient.)

If you're having to report on a specific month then you'll need to alter the initial cte that defines [FirstDate] and [LastDate]

```
DROP TABLE #Clientvisit

CREATE TABLE #ClientVisit(
VisitID INT
,AdmitDateTime DATETIME
,DischargeDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #ClientVisit
VALUES
(1,'20160604 13:50','20160606 03:50')
,(2,'20160604 13:50','20160609 13:50')


--IF YOU'RE NOT USING A CALENDAR TABLE THEN USE RECURSIVE CTE TO BUILD DATE LIST
;WITH cte
    AS
    (
    SELECT
        MIN(CAST(AdmitDateTime AS DATE)) AS FirstDate
        ,MAX(CAST(DischargeDateTime AS DATE)) AS LastDate
    FROM
        #ClientVisit
    )
,cte_R
    AS
    (
    SELECT FirstDate,LastDate FROM cte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,FirstDate),LastDate FROM cte_R
    WHERE DATEADD(DD,1,FirstDate) <= LastDate
    )
SELECT
    c.FirstDate
    ,COUNT(v.VisitID) AS BedDays
FROM
    cte_R c
        LEFT JOIN #ClientVisit v
            ON
            DATEADD(DD
                    ,1  --PLAY WITH THIS VALUE EITHER -1/0/1 TO ALLIGN THE BEDDAYS WITH THE DESIRED DATE
                    ,c.FirstDate) BETWEEN v.AdmitDateTime AND v.DischargeDateTime
GROUP BY
    c.FirstDate
```