# Hibernate Criteria select using embedded object (tuple)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, embeddable

In my case I have a SQL query which looks like:

```
select * from event_instance where (object_id, object_type) in 
    (<LIST OF TUPLES RETRIEVED FROM SUBQUERY>);
```

I want to map this on Hibernate Entities and I have a problem with this query. My mapping looks like that:

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name="event_instance")
     public class AuditEvent {
         <OTHER_FIELDS>

         @Column( name = "object_type", nullable = false)
         private String objectType;

         @Column( name ="object_id" , nullable = false)
         private Integer objectId;
     }
```

and second entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(schema = "els" ,name = "acg_objects")
    public class AcgObject implements Serializable{

        @Id
        @Column(name = "acg_id")
        private String acgId;

        @Id
        @Column(name="object_type")
        private String objectType;

        @Id
        @Column(name="object_id")
        private Integer objectId;

        <OTHER FIELDS>

}
```

I already run query for getting AcgObjects and for my DAO I'm getting List only thing I want to do is query a touple using criteria like:

```
      crit.add(Restrictions.in("objectType,objectId",<List of tuples>);
```

Is it possible? I was trying to use @Embedded object but don't know how exactly construct a query for it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that not in standard SQL nor using criteria; you have to split in two distinct restrictions or using a [`Session.SQLQuery()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery(java.lang.String)) if you want to use specific RDBMS (look at [SQL WHERE.. IN clause multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns) for an explanation)