# Global temp table across different databases SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I've got two tables in two databases. I need to set a flag in database a where the row exists in database b.
I was thinking of using an SSIS package and storing b in a global temp table, then setting the flags in a by using that global temp table. 
Is this scoping possible?

Here are my queries. Both are in different tasks.
Database b to global temp table

```
SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
INTO ##TempWatchList
FROM [TblWatchList]
```

From a based on the global temp table

```
SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[WatchFlag]
FROM [Patient]
WHERE ([FirstName], [LastName]) IN
(
    SELECT [FirstName], [LastName]
    FROM ##TempWatchList
)
```

I've tried it and got the following error

"An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I also changed the global temp table's name to an invalid one and got the same error.
If that level of scoping doesn't work what else could I do besides creating a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually are seeing an error that is unrelated to your temp table - trying to use two different columns with your `IN` operator.  To get this functionality, you would have to concatenate the two values in both your WHERE clause and the IN clause, like so:

```
SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[WatchFlag]
FROM [Patient]
WHERE ([FirstName]+ '|' + [LastName]) IN
(
    SELECT [FirstName]+ '|' + [LastName]
    FROM ##TempWatchList
)
```

EDIT: if the concatenation doesn't work for you, try some of the solutions suggested under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns).

Based on that, the most performant option would be the one posed by MrDenny, which looks like this:

```
SELECT [FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[WatchFlag]
FROM [Patient]
WHERE EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM ##TempWatchList wl
    WHERE 
        wl.FirstName = Patient.FirstName AND 
        wl.LastName = Patient.LastName
  )
```

Comment: Tried that and got "Invalid object name '##TempWatchList'.", so I guess you can't use a global temp table across different databases?

Comment: Actually, that's a good thing - it means you've fixed one error, and now you can work on the one you thought you had.  Step through the walkthrough [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/) on adding temp variables to SSIS, and let me know if you are able to get it working.

Comment: I got it working, but it's really slow. I'd imagine it's from the concatenation. I don't suppose there's another way? I was thinking of making a temp table in the destination database and using that to query against the table, but SSIS doesn't let me select it.

Comment: I've edited to include an alternative (and linked to a question with more).  Should you consider just making a real table out of this?  What is the benefit of having it in a temp table?

Comment: The only reason for it being in a temp table is because the data won't be permanently stored there. It's only needed to set flags when it runs. Thinking about that for a second it'll be way faster to make a permanent table. It's just that I don't have control over that db. I'm going to try inserting that concatenated variable into a temp table and see how that works out. It's a little slow, not as slow as the other way but it should do for now.

Comment: Thanks it'll do for now, at least until I figure out how use a data flow task to insert into a temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. you cannot use this `WHERE (column1, column2) IN (col1,col2)` instead you have to use AND operator `where column1 = col1 and column2 = col2`

```
SELECT [FirstName],
       [LastName],
       [WatchFlag]
FROM   [Patient]
WHERE  [FirstName] IN (SELECT [FirstName]
                       FROM   ##TempWatchList)
       AND [LastName] IN (SELECT [LastName]
                         FROM   ##TempWatchList)
```

Comment: Querying the two names independently would not return the right values: what if a FirstName shows up with record 321 in ##TempWatchList, but a LastName shows up with record 986?

Comment: Actually, the AND operator there would be perfectly satisfied if the FirstName under consideration was found in any row of ##TempWatchList, as long as the LastName was also found in any row (which might or might not be the same row as the FirstName).