# How to convert Oracle to MS SQL with multiple parameters in where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have this Oracle query :

```
   SELECT company, structure_id, team_code 
   FROM structure_main_tab 
   WHERE (company, parent_structure_id, team_code) 
   IN (SELECT company, structure_id, team_code 
      FROM structure_main_tab 
      WHERE (company, parent_structure_id, team_code) 
      IN (SELECT company, structure_id, team_code 
          FROM company_user_tab 
          WHERE UPPER(fusername) = UPPER('xxx') AND fdeleted = 'N'
          )
   );
```

I am trying to convert this oracle query to a SQL server query.

can anyone help me please?

Comment: You'll have to write it into separate `WHERE` clauses with `AND` in between. On a side-note: the first subselect uses the same table as the main query, is that correct?

Comment: Think you can't use multiple columns for IN in Sql Server. You may look at 2 `EXISTS` clause instead of IN.

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: @NickyvV i've tried it..but i just can't get the same result as the oracle's query. can you help me?

Comment: @Yoga: You explain what is wrong. Just pasting code and telling it doesn't work isn't the way it works here.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can't use multiple columns for an IN clause in Sql Server.

I would replace by an exists clause and a join

```
SELECT company, structure_id, team_code 
   FROM structure_main_tab  smt
   WHERE EXISTS (select null from 
                 structure_main_tab smt1
                 join company_user_tab cut on cut.company = smt1.company and 
                                              cut.structure_id = smt1.parent_structure_id and
                                              cut.team_code = smt1.team_code
                where UPPER(cut.fusername) = UPPER('xxx') AND cut.fdeleted = 'N'  
                and smt.company = smt1.company 
                and smt.parent_structure_id = smt1.structure_id
                and smt.team_code = smt1.team_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below query :

```
     SELECT company, structure_id, team_code into #temp1 
      FROM company_user_tab 
      WHERE UPPER(fusername) = UPPER('xxx') AND fdeleted = 'N'





      SELECT company, structure_id, team_code
      FROM structure_main_tab Mt inner join #temp1 tt 
      on Mt.company=tt.company and mt.parent_structure_id=tt.structure_id
      and mt.team_code=tt.team_code
```