# In one-to-many, how to express "where exists" in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

Let's assume two tables:

- cats, `Cat`
- personality traits, `Personality_Trait`

were `Cat` has an `id` and `Personality_Trait` has an `id` and a string `trait`.

e.g.

```
== Cat ==
id  |  name
---------------
0   |  Tom
1   |  Garfield
2   |  Kitty

== Personality_Trait ===
id  |  trait
---------------
0   |  stubborn
1   |  stubborn
1   |  sleepy
1   |  moody
2   |  sleepy
2   |  moody
```

How do I get all cats that have at least all the traits I'm interested in?

e.g. how do I get `Garfield` when I'm looking for `stubborn` and `moody`

I was thinking of something like

```
Personality_Trait.groupBy(_.id).filter {
  case (id, traits) => <predicate on traits>
}.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, albeit inelegant and potentially inefficient:

```
val desiredTraits = Set("stubborn", "moody")

(for {
  catId <- Personality_Trait.filter(_.trait inSetBind desiredTraits)
             .groupBy(_.id).map { case (txnId, foundTraits) =>
               (txnId, foundTraits.length)
             }.filter { case (txnId, foundTraitCount) =>
               foundTraitCount >= desiredTraits.size
             }.map(_._1)
  cat <- Cat if cat.id === catId
} yield (cat)).result
```

Comment: You can replace your "Where exists" with a proper join : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns

Answer (score -1):

I think firstly you should translate Personality_Trait from (id, trait) to tempRecord (id,seq[trait]) and then do predicate on that.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. That is exactly what I'm proposing in the question (`Personality_Trait.groupBy(_.id)` effectively does that), however I don't know how to express the predicate in a way that's understood by Slick. If this wasn't slick I'd check that `traits.toSet.subsetOf(desiredTraits.toSet)`.

Comment: You can't or not easy to  using "Slick" data set to filter that information. beside, the easist way is as I said to change it to  (id,seq[trait]) format below is what you need to implement rather than using groupBy   the expected format as following  //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Stri
                                                  //| ng]] = Map(0 -> List(stubborn), 1 -> List(stubborn, sleepy, moody), 2 -> Lis
                                                  //| t(sleepy, moody))

Comment: Sadly, doing anything like that would mean to load the entire dataset in ram for every query. My question is about how get slick to write a reasonable sql query for this use case.

Comment: I think your solution will also load entire dataset to ram for every query. But your solution is "Slick" way to the question. And for my solution If the Temp Record is created, no need to visit the whole dataset when another query comes bacause visit TempRecord instead, your solution will visit the dataset for every query. There should trade off for both solution.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to represent `tempRecord` as a slick table (how would you store the `Seq[Trait]` in a single row in a way that's indexable? - provided we stay with basic sql types). Please keep in mind that this question is specifically about *slick*. I've run an `explain query plan` on the resulting query on sqlite and I can assure you that, even though the query is not optimal, it does not require loading the entire dataset in ram (at least from the perspective of the client); there are no full scans either.