# Using more than two where clauses in the single update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
EmpId   EmpName   ManagerId   Gender                  
1       Shahzad       2         M         
2       Santosh       1         F         
3       Sayanhi       2         M
```

By mistake 'M' is assigned to female employees and 'F' is assigned to male employees. So I need to write a query to make the correction.

I tried the below query.

```
UPDATE Employee 
SET Gender='M' 
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM Employee WHERE Gender='F') 
  AND Gender='F'
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT EmpId FROM Employee WHERE Gender='M')
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here is a simple solution that will fix both cases at once:

```
UPDATE Employee
SET Gender = CASE Gender
  WHEN 'M' THEN 'F'
  WHEN 'F' THEN 'M'
END
```

Comment: Yours is better :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT   empid, empname, CASE WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 'F' ELSE 'M' END AS Gender
INTO     #tmp
FROM     Employee
```

If you're happy with what you see in there, then:

```
UPDATE    Employee
SET       Employee.Gender = #tmp.Gender
FROM      Employee
INNER JOIN #tmp
ON        Employee.empid = #tmp.empid
```

Comment: Sorry - qualified `Employee.Gender` - should work now.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a given that every employee's gender is incorrect, and every gender is already M or F, why not:

```
UPDATE Employee
   SET Gender=(CASE WHEN Gender='F' 
                    THEN 'M' 
                    ELSE 'F' END)
```