# Multicolumn WHERE-IN clause in QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

I'm new to QueryDSL and would to be able to assemble a query with multiple columns in the WHERE-IN clause, like the following query:

```
selec T1.COL1, T1.COL2, .... T1.COL10 
from T1
where (T1.COL1, T1.COL2) IN (select T2.COL1, T2.COL2 from T2 WHERE T2.COL3='a' AND T2.COL4='b')
```

I have the part of the main query down:

```
List<Tuple> result = queryFactory.select(t1.col,...,t1.col10)
.from(t1)
.where(???) // This is the part I'm missing
.fetch();
```

But I don't know how to implement the where clause. How can this be done in QueryDSL?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use joins, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1136382/2078908).

Comment: @ursa: a join is not necessarily a replacement for an IN condition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem and it took me a day to find the solution to it. You can use *Expressions.list()* to specify more than one column for the in clause.

So here's what you should have in your *where()* clause:

```
Expressions.list(t1.col1, t1.col2).in(
    JPAExpressions.select(t2.col1, t2.col2)
                      .from(t2)
                      .where(...)
)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I no longer work on the QueryDSL project, so unable to test this answer in a reasonable time investment. I'm accepting because I trust that this is the way to do it. Thank you, Timi!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about selecting multiple fields in the sub-query, but for one field it works as follows, using `JPASubQuery`:

```
ListSubQuery<Integer> subQuery = new JPASubQuery()
    .from(t2)
    .where(t2.col3.eq('a')).and(t2.col4.eq('b'))
    .list(t2.col1);
```

And then use it in your query:

```
List<Tuple> result = queryFactory.select(t1.col,...,t1.col10)
    .from(t1)
    .where(t1.col1.in(subQuery))
    .fetch();
```

Maybe multiple fields work by using `ListSubQuery<Tuple>`.

Comment: But the question is about using more then one column in the `IN` condition.