# Selecting multiple columns in tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to select guid and uuid appear in the inner table, but the following syntax is not allowed in SQL Server 2016, how should I do it?

```
select * 
from myTable
where (guid, uuid) in (select max(guid) as maxguid, convert(nvarchar(max), uuid) as uuid 
                       from myTable
                       group by convert(nvarchar(max), uuid) 
                      )
```

I have seen other answers like [SQL WHERE.. IN clause multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns) But I have a group by statement in my inner table, not sure how to use them.

Comment: Why do you perform `max` on `guid`? I suppose guid is a string. Do you want DISTINCT here? If there are multiple match in myTable, do you want to select them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the grouping in inner-subquery and use exists for multiple columns

```
select * from myTable
where exists
(select 1
 from (select max(guid) as maxguid, convert(nvarchar(max), uuid) as uuid
       from myTable
       group by convert(nvarchar(max), uuid)) innerTable
 where myTable.guid = innerTable.maxguid
 and myTable.uuid = innerTable.uuid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query and a join - something along the lines of

```
select 
  myTable.* 
from 
  myTable join 
  (  
    select 
      max(guid) as maxguid, 
      convert(nvarchar(max), uuid) as uuid 
    from 
      myTable
    group by
      convert(nvarchar(max), uuid) 
  ) x
  on 
    x.maxguid = myTable.guid and 
    x.uuid = myTable.uuid
```