# Find all records that contain a combination of attributes from an array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, arel

I have a table called `LayerProducts` that contains `layer_id` and `product_id` attributes.

I would like to create a query where I can pass in an array of arrays that looks like this:

```
[ [:layer1_id, :product1_id], [:layer2_id, :product2_id], [:layer3_id, :product3_id] ]
```

and return all records of `LayerProduct` that contain any of the combinations supplied.

The parent array is not fixed-length, so the query would need to be dynamic to accommodate any number of combinations.

Is this possible and if so, how would I go about creating this query using either SQL or active record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a raw sql and use active record.
Something like this:

```
def self.for_multiple_lp(arr=[])
  # Handle case when arr is not in the expected format.
  condition = arr.collect{|a| "(layer_id = #{a[0]} AND product_id = #{a[1]})"}.join(" OR ")
  where(condition)
end
```

For just raw sql without activerecord you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns)