# Update where exists, referencing the table being updated?

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a table where one of the conditions is an `EXISTS` that needs to reference the table being updated.

I couldn't find a neat way to do this, so I resorted to this verbose SQL that gets the job done:

```
update TABLE_R set
   _deleted = 1
where id in (
   select id from TABLE_R r
   where (r.connectId = @theID)
   and (isnull(r._deleted, 0) = 0)
   and (r.type = 'Person')
   and exists(
      select id from TABLE_P p
      where (isnull(p.deleted, 0) = 1)
      and (isnull(p.social_security, '') <> '')
      and (p.social_security = r.social_security)
      and (p.trans_id = r.trans_id)
   )
)
```

Is there any way to simplify this? It seems like there should be a way to remove the outer nested `select` - but I couldn't find a way to reference `TABLE_R` in the `EXISTS` clause unless I wrap it in `SELECT id FROM TABLE_R r`.

Any ideas? Or is this as good as it gets?

I don't want to use `JOIN`, and I want to keep it as readable and simple as possible.

Comment: An explanation of the purpose of the query, as would sample data and desired results.

Comment: and why do you not want to use a JOIN? That would be the way to do it.  Or use a CTE query.  You can use an alias on the table name and then update it using joins.

Comment: @Brad Mostly to avoid common mistakes when joining, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54389589/930640 . I want to keep it as simple, readable and predictable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Whould this work? Since this is an UPDATE, PLEASE make sure you run this on test data, and also run it as a select first to verify the results.

```sql
UPDATE r SET _deleted = 1
--SELECT *
FROM TABLE_R r
WHERE r.connectId = @theID
    AND ISNULL(r._deleted, 0) = 0
    AND r.[type] = 'Person'
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM TABLE_P p
        WHERE p.deleted = 1
            AND p.social_security <> ''
            AND p.social_security = r.social_security
            AND s.trans_id = r.trans_id
    )
```

I removed a couple things.

```sql
(isnull(p.deleted, 0) = 1)
```

The `ISNULL()` is not needed here since you want `p.deleted = 1`, that will filter out NULL's anyway.

```sql
and (isnull(p.social_security, '') <> '')
```

I also removed this `ISNULL()` since `p.social_security = r.social_security` will eliminate the NULL's as well, but you still want to avoid joining on blank `social_security`'s.

Answer (score 1):

In Sql Server, you can take your logic out of the `in` clause.  Outside of that, you can make it a bit more readable by avoiding parentheses when not necessary.  The `exists` clause may seem verbose, but it's actually going to be the most performant way you can do it.  But for readability I like to `select 0` to make it clear we don't care about the results.

```
update  r
set     _deleted = 1
from    TABLE_R r
where   r.connectId = @theID
and     isnull(r._deleted, 0) = 0
and     r.type = 'Person'
and     exists(
            select  0
            from    TABLE_P p
            where   isnull(p.deleted, 0) = 1
            and     isnull(p.social_security, '') <> ''
            and     p.social_security = r.social_security
            and     s.trans_id = r.trans_id
        )
```