# Is multiple JOINS using subquery possible?

Tags: sql

I have tried to do a JOIN using a subquery and it works.

INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM students
JOIN teacher ON teacher.id = students.master_teacher
```

INNER JOIN using Subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM students
WHERE master_teacher IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM teacher
        )
```

But if I want to implement multiple JOIN, is it possible?. Below is the multiple join that I need to:

Multiple JOIN:

```
SELECT honstudent.f_name
    ,students.student_id
    ,students.master_teacher
    ,teacher.full_name
FROM honstudent
JOIN students ON honstudent.s_id = students.student_id
JOIN teacher ON teacher.id = students.master_teacher
```

I understand that the subquery doesn't allow more than one column.

Comment: the Multiple join; is how SQL works and if designed appropriately: how an RDBMS should work.  Your "Inner join using a sub query" isn't a join at all; as you can't select data columns from from the `teacher` table.   The "IN" clause is just limiting the data returned from students.  you can uses "`Exists`" instead of IN to do "Multiple columns" and "IN" does support multiple columns, you just have to read how to do it; though I don't recommend it.

Comment: Seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns/1136381

Comment: So what's the problem with your last query - it has two joins - that's multiple. What is the problem you are trying to solve?