# stackoverflow db schema - multi-column join SLOW with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm doing some performance testing and the StackOverflow2010 DB is great for this.

Looking here for testing multi-column joins [SQL WHERE.. IN clause multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns)

The StackOverflow DB is available here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/

I'm trying to query for Comments for Posts for specific users:

```sql
-- get users id < 5
SELECT *
FROM [Users]
WHERE Id < 5;

-- get posts for those users
SELECT *
FROM [Posts]
WHERE [OwnerUserId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [Users] WHERE Id < 5);

-- get comments for these posts 
SELECT *
FROM [Comments]
WHERE [PostId] IN (SELECT [Id]
                   FROM [Posts]
                   WHERE [OwnerUserId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [Users] WHERE Id < 5))
  AND [UserId] IN (SELECT [OwnerUserId]
                   FROM [Posts]
                   WHERE [OwnerUserId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [Users] WHERE Id < 5));

-- THIS version seems to select ALL comments and takes forever!
SELECT *
FROM [Comments]
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM [Posts]
              WHERE [OwnerUserId] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM [Users] WHERE Id < 5));
```

The `IN` query works but it selects some Comments that the `OwnerUserId` didn't make (orphans).

The `EXISTS` query (which seems to be the correct way) seems to select ALL comments and takes forever!

Any ideas? The reason for this is explained here: https://sproket.github.io/Persism/n+1.html

Comment: Your subquery in the `EXISTS` isn't correlated. As such it *will* return *every* row in the table `Comments` as the query within the `EXISTS` is going to find *at least* one row that *exists*. In fact, *none* of your subqueries are correlated.

Comment: Have you tried doing actual JOINs instead of EXISTS/IN queries? Also, why `AND [UserId] IN (<double nested subquery>)` instead of `AND [UserId] < 5`?

Comment: @Larnu I added a link to explain the reasoning. It all works fine with single column joins.

Comment: If the information is related to the question, put it in the question, @sproketboy . Don't require users to visit a link to a Git repository to be able to understand the question .

Comment: @Larnu OK I'll ask the question again with the additional information.

Answer (score 2):

You are massively overly complicating the issue here.

Firstly, let's have a look at your second query. This doesn't actually need to reference the `Users` table at all. You're looking for details of Posts where the User ID is < 5, and the User ID is already in the `Posts` table, `OwnerUserId`. So you could just write your second query as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Posts
WHERE OwnerUserId < 5;
```

For your next query, the same applies again, you don't need the subqueries, the ID of the user is already in the `Comments` table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Comments
WHERE UserId < 5;
```

As for your `EXISTS` the reason it isn't working is because it isn't correlated. As such the subquery in your `EXISTS` *always* returns at least one row, and so the `EXISTS` evaluates to TRUE; and so *every* row in the table `Comments` is returned.

A correlated query would look something like this (this is not relevant to the queries you have, as they are overly complicated):

```sql
SELECT {Columns}
FROM dbo.SomeTable ST
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.OtherTable OT
              WHERE OT.OtherInt > 10
                AND OT.SomeID = ST.ID);
```

Note the clause `OT.SomeID = ST.ID` which means that the tables `dbo.SomeTable` and `dbo.OtherTable` have some relationship. As such the above query would only return rows from `dbo.SomeTable` where a related row existed in `dbo.OtherTable` *and* that related row has a value greater than `10` in the column `OtherInt`.

Comment: The reason for the complexity is that these queries need to be generalized as part my Persism library. Using single column joins with IN allows me to get child rows quickly while avoiding the SELECT N+1 problem.

Comment: Like I mentioned, those subqueries are simply *not* required in any of the above attempts, @sproketboy . Perhaps the problem is that you have used a poor example to demonstrate what you are *actually* trying to achieve and that was resulted in you writing incorrect and overly complicated SQL. If so, you may well need to ask a new question, detailing your actual problem.