# Subquery error while executing the code below

Tags: subquery

Hello while executing this subquery i am getting the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected, near ','.

```
select Emp_Name, Salary
from Employee 
where (Dep_ID, Salary) in (Select Dep_ID, max(salary) as highest_salary
                                          from Employee
                                          group by Dep_ID);
```

Though I tried changing the datatype to Varchar(max), it is not working.

Comment: Please tag what RDBMS you're using.

Comment: The RDMS used here is SSMS

Comment: Assuming you use SQL Server, since SSMS is the client to connect to it -- then you can't do this. SQL Server does not allow `in` clause with multiple fields. See this for options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns