# Not in Subquery

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, window-functions

The following employee table shows which department(s) an employee is in and which one is their primary department. If an employee only belongs to one department their primary flag will show 'N' (even though that is their primary department as it's their only one) and if they have multiple departments it will flag 'Y' or 'N' to show which one is primary.

Employee:

| employee_id | department_id | primary_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | N |
| 2 | 1 | Y |
| 2 | 2 | N |
| 3 | 3 | N |
| 4 | 2 | N |
| 4 | 3 | Y |
| 4 | 4 | N |

Expected output--the primary department for employee_id is department_id

| employee_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

My solution returns nothing.

Why does it not work?

There are no null values and when I run the subquery by itself it shows the employee_id, department_ids that should not be in the final output.

```
select employee_id, department_id 
from Employee
WHERE (employee_id, department_id) not in(
    select employee_id, department_id 
    from (
        SELECT employee_id, department_id, primary_flag,
            count(employee_id) over (partition by employee_id) as cnt
        from employee
    ) a 
    WHERE cnt > 1 and primary_flag = 'n'
);
```

[image]

From Joel Coehoorn's comments below, he was able to produce the same results; however it does not work for me in LeetCode.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, only paste as text.

Comment: If you need two columns for the `IN()` or `NOT IN()` expressions, you're usually better off writing it as a JOIN instead. Also, not every database allows multiple columns there at all. SQL Server, for example, would not allow this and you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: start by running your subqueries and seeing which does not return what you expect?

Comment: Again: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please put what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at another page or post or comment, giving credit in visible text & formatting as a quote, & relate to your question--posts should  be self-contained. Please clarify via edits, not comments; delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 2):

**Your query is much much too complicated.** This doesn't need any subqueries or windows functions at all.

All you need is some conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  e.employee_id,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1
       THEN MIN(e.department_id)
       ELSE MIN(CASE WHEN e.primary_flag = 'Y' THEN e.department_id END)
  END AS department_id
FROM Employee e
GROUP BY
  e.employee_id;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/4uz6P9qh)

---

Your existing query has multiple issues:

- Because the values *might* have a null, MySQL evaluates the `NOT IN` clause differently. You can see this in action in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ug4b5C25).
  Generally you should avoid `NOT IN`, it can always be rewritten as a `NOT EXISTS`.
- Row comparators don't work in all DBMSs.
- In any case you could have simplified out and removed the self-join.

  ```sql
  select employee_id, department_id 
  from (
      SELECT employee_id, department_id, primary_flag,
          count(employee_id) over (partition by employee_id) as cnt
      from Employee
  ) a 
  WHERE cnt = 1 or primary_flag = 'y';
  ```

  Obviously it's not necessary to use window functions anyway, as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: the question asks why the query does not work.  "Because the values might have a null, MySQL evaluates the NOT IN clause differently. You can see this in action in this fiddle." - this seems to be the answer, but could use some elaboration

Comment: TBH I am actually not sure why it does this, it's only supposed to do that when there are actual nulls in the subquery. Maybe MySQL is different from other DBMSs, I couldn't find any docs on this point.

Comment: I think it's just a bug.  works in mariadb

Comment: thanks @Charlieface. I am aware that my query can be simplified. I was playing around with it and was trying to solve the problems in all the ways I know how. I built this out and saw it did not work. It is strange because there is no NULLs in the data. I can see that there may be nulls, but trying to see why it wont work when there is no nulls ( and even if you specify department_id not null and employee_id not null, it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best is using `row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by case when primary = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end) as rnk` and then only keep the rows where this result is 1 (`where rnk=1`), as suggested by @JoelCoehoorn.

If you want to use a subquery for condition WHERE IN (NOT IN), see example

```
select employee_id, department_id 
from Employee
WHERE primary_flag='Y' 
  or employee_id not in(select employee_id from Employee where primary_flag='Y')
```

Output

| employee_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

Your query is complex. I would try to simplify the logic.

Overall, there are only two cases regarding the primary department for a given employee_id:

1, when count(department_id) =1 , then that department_id is the primary department regardless the primary_flag always being 'N'. To conclude, the focus is `the count(department_id) =1`

2, when count(department_id) >1 , then the department_id whose primary_flag is 'Y' is the primary department . In short, the vital part is `primary_flag is 'Y'`.

As the two cases are mutually exclusive, using `UNION` is possible without worrying overlap. Besides, the logic is straight. And the query  optimization job is more relaxing as each union statement has its separate use of index.

```
select * from
    (select employee_id, max(department_id)
    from employee
    group by employee_id
    having count(*) =1
    UNION
    select employee_id, department_id
    from employee
    where primary_flag='Y'
    ) t
order by employee_id
;
-- result:
+-------------+--------------------+
| employee_id | max(department_id) |
+-------------+--------------------+
|           1 | 1                  |
|           2 | 1                  |
|           3 | 3                  |
|           4 | 3                  |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Note: The reason of putting `UNION` statements in a derived table is because `UNION` statements don't enforce the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Table structure suggestion**

The current table `Employee (employee_id int, department_id int, primary_flag char(1))` design requires some query depth to get the primary department. And the primary_flag does not check if multiple 'Y' for a given employee_id exist in the data set.

I would suggest dropping the primary_flag column in the current table. Then create a table `primary_department` as below.

```
-- Note: Make sure you have a key for (employee_id ,department_id) on table `Employee` or create one now. And in this case , a unique key is recommended which warrants the uniqueness of `employee_id-department_id` pair.

create unique index idx_employeeid_departmentid on Employee (employee_id ,department_id);

create table primary_department
(employee_id int,p_department_id int, primary key (employee_id),
constraint `fk` foreign key (employee_id ,p_department_id) references Employee(employee_id ,department_id) 
);
```

By doing this, we can directly query for the primary department. In addtion, we can guarantee no conflicting primary departments for a given employee_id exist.

Answer (score -1):

I combined Employee and Department together

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee] 
(
    [employee_id]   INT,
    [department_id] VARCHAR(512),
    [primary_flag]  VARCHAR(512)
);

INSERT INTO [Employee] ([employee_id], [department_id], [primary_flag]) VALUES
    ('1', '1', 'N'),
    ('2', '1', 'Y'),
    ('2', '2', 'N'),
    ('3', '3', 'N'),
    ('4', '2', 'N'),
    ('4', '3', 'Y'),
    ('4', '4', 'N');

Select * from Employee

select employee_id, department_id 
from Employee
WHERE cast(employee_id as varchar(10)) + '|' + cast(department_id as varchar(10)) not in(
    select cast(employee_id as varchar(10)) + '|' + cast(department_id as varchar(10))  
    from (
        SELECT employee_id, department_id, primary_flag,
            count(employee_id) over (partition by employee_id) as cnt
        from employee
    ) a 
    WHERE cnt > 1 and primary_flag = 'n'
);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JU3euYv-)

| employee_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

Comment: For similar solutions see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136380/sql-where-in-clause-multiple-columns

Comment: Hi Bart - Appreciate it. I understand why your solution does work. I also know of other ways to make this work. What I am trying to determine is why my current solution does not work - just for my own understanding

Comment: @MichaelNorman This answer was written for SQL Server. Here is a corrected fiddle using MySQL https://dbfiddle.uk/r5BzUlgA

Comment: @MichaelNorman Note it actually DOES WORK... so at the moment this question is "no repro".

Comment: @MichaelNorman oh, but I did have to correct the case of the table name to match the definition (Employee instead of employee). MySQL can be picky about that.

Comment: @MichaelNorman Finally, fwiw I would use window functions to solve this, but I'd use `row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by case when primary = 'Y' then 0 else 1 end)` and then only keep the rows where this result is `1`. I'd expect that to run much faster and save a level (or even two) of nesting in the query.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That is so strange. Even when I just copy paste the same exact way you wrote it, in Leetcode, it does not work. Must be something wrong on their system then. No wonder this has baffled me for many days. 

And thanks for the tip on the window function