# getting data from 2 different table with JOIN sql. Codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

I use codeigniter, and I need to get data from 2 different table. for now it returns data only from works_image table. how can I get data from both 2 table ?

thanks a lot!!

```
$this->db->select('works_image.*', 'works.*');
$this->db->from('works_image', 'works');
$this->db->join('works', 'works.id = works_image.id_work');
$result = $this->db->get();

foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
    echo " # " . $row->id . " - " . $row->thumb . " - " . $row->wname . "
";
}
```

Comment: MAybe this post will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024800/codeigniter-table-join

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're doing a `SELECT *` ([Why is this a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346659/what-are-the-most-common-sql-anti-patterns/346679#346679)), you shouldn't need to specify tables with the call to `select()`.  It will select all fields by default.

```
$this->db->from('works_image', 'works');
$this->db->join('works', 'works.id = works_image.id_work');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Should work fine.

Instead, what you really should be doing, is specifying exactly which fields you need:

```
$this->db->select('works_image.id, works_image.name, works_image.id_work, works.id, works.name'); // (or whichever fields you're interested in)
$this->db->from('works_image', 'works');
$this->db->join('works', 'works.id = works_image.id_work');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

This way you can be sure that (a) you're not pulling unnecessary data from your DB, and (b) your code won't break if/when you modify your DB schema.

Comment: thanks for advice : ) I used .* because of I already have only few parameters at table. they are not big tables. or do you think no matter how smal table is that, i should specify exactly which fields i need?

Comment: It's always a good idea, regardless of the size of the table, to specify exactly which fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

This post should answer your question: http://www.whypad.com/posts/codeigniter-activerecord-join-tip/178/

In short, you need to rewrite your select statement from

```
$this->db->select('works_image.*', 'works.*');
```

to this:

```
$this->db->select('works_image.*, works.*');
```

Note that this was the first result on Google for 'CodeIgniter join'. Try Googling your questions first. You can often get yourself a faster answer :)

Comment: I actually have searched at google for hours and hours :/ to find a quick solution, but I could not notice that ' ' point :/ blind me! it is working great now!!! thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be to write below code

```
$this->db->select('works_image.*', 'works.*');
$this->db->from('works_image');
$this->db->join('works', 'works.id = works_image.id_work');
$result = $this->db->get();

foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
echo " # " . $row->id . " - " . $row->thumb . " - " . $row->wname . "
";
}
```

I think that you get your result