# codeigniter table join

Tags: codeigniter, join, html-table

I want to display both the user table and users_profiles table in 1 table :
I want to link them both so that usrpID = usrID,

Before this process I tried displaying only users table using this code and it works great.

Controller:

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users_profiles');
$this->load->view('users/users_view',$data);
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($query->result_array() as $row): ?>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td><?php echo $row['usrID']</td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrName'];?></td>
        </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

but when I try to join two tables, it returns me an error: this is my code

```
$this->db->select('users.usrID, users_profiles.usrpID');
$this->db->from('users', 'users_profiles');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.usrID = users_profiles.usrpID');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

users table has fields like username,password, etc. and every user has his own profile in users_profiles table

```
users           users_profiles
```

[image: users table][image: users_profiles table]

**EDIT** I tried selecting the fields but when I tried this

```
<td><?php echo $row['usrID'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpFirstName'].' '.$row['usrpLastName'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpBday'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpSex'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['usrpAddress'];?></td>
```

it returns me the first value in users profiles in which it should not

Comment: What version of CI are you using? What error are you getting? Have you tried the query without using the query builder?

Comment: i am using the newest version of CI.. it returns me an error about no unique/alias table.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`users` table was in both `from` and `join` functions, so in sum you were joining 3 tables: `users`, `users` and `users_profiles` -> the 2 first have the same name -> *error unique/alias table*.

Try this (joining [`users` in `from`] on [`users_profiles` in `join`]):

```
$this->db->select('users.usrID, users_profiles.usrpID')
         ->from('users')
         ->join('users_profiles', 'users.usrID = users_profiles.usrpID');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

### EDIT:

example:

To get `users_profiles` `userpNick` column:

```
$this->db->select('users.usrID, users_profiles.userpNick')
         ->from('users')
         ->join('users_profiles', 'users.usrID = users_profiles.usrpID');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

view:

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row): ?>
        <tr class="even gradeC">
            <td><?php echo $row->usrID</td>
            <td><?php echo $row->userpNick;?></td>
        </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: how can i display also the columns in users_profiles table? i can only get data from users table using <?php echo $row['usrID'];?></td>, because i want to display also the profile of each usrID, thanks

Comment: In the `select` function, put whatever columns you want to retrieve from the database. They will be available as members via `->` notation.

Comment: using $row-> will return me a message like this : Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: the `$query` (what you store in `$data['query']`) in `foreach` must be the result of `$this->db->get()`. Is this the case?

Comment: yes, but thanks, i finally get it working, it should be $this->db->join('users_profiles', 'users.usrID = users_profiles.usrID'); not $this->db->join('users_profiles', 'users.usrID = users_profiles.usrpID');

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this example of join result between employee and address table.

```
function getEmployees(){
  $this->db->select("trn_employee.EMPLOYEE_ID,trn_employee.FIRST_NAME,trn_employee.LAST_NAME,trn_employee.EMAIL,trn_address.ADDRESS_LINE,trn_address.CITY");
  $this->db->from('trn_employee');
  $this->db->join('trn_address', 'trn_address.employee_id = trn_employee.employee_id');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```