# Joining two or more tables in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

I'm very new to the concept of joining two tables in CodeIgniter query. Can someone explain the meaning of each line of these codes, please? I don't understand them at all.

```
    $this->db->select('d.*, u.first_name, u.last_name');          
    $this->db->where('status', -1);        
    $this->db->join('users AS u','u.id = d.user_id');
    $this->db->order_by('d.date','desc');
    return $this->db->get('dtr AS d');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [codeigniter table join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024800/codeigniter-table-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just refer to codeigniter user guide [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)
And i suggest if you are not compatible on doing that way try to code like this:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name";
   $this->db->query($sql);
```

It is just the same way around.

Answer (score 1):

Joins is not a CodeIgniter concept but a relational database concept. The SQL code of this query is :

```
SELECT d.*, u.first_name, u.last_name'
FROM dtr AS d 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = d.user_id
WHERE status = -1
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

the query calls two table and joins them using a common key (user: id and dtr: id).