# Nested joins in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

How to run this sql query in Codeigniter framework?

```
SELECT  users.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(category.title SEPARATOR ',') as title 
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN (
    procducts as pr 
    INNER JOIN category ON pr.category_id =category.id
  ) 
  ON (users.id=pr.user_id)   
GROUP BY users.id
```

using Active Record (Query Builder Class) in Codeigniter without using `db->query`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [codeigniter table join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024800/codeigniter-table-join)

Comment: @hamza-zafee i see this link before asked question

Answer (score 1):

The Codeigniter docs [explain a join](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::join) like follows:

```
join($table, $cond[, $type = ''[, $escape = NULL]])
```

there is no documentation on nested join support. So you could create a query like:

```
$this->db->select('users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(category.title SEPARATOR ',') as title')
         ->from('users')
         ->join('procducts as pr INNER JOIN category ON pr.category_id =category.id','users.id=pr.user_id','left')
         ->group_by('users.id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: it's have got a little problem in '``' before and affter pr.procducts

Comment: please explain your problem, what is the generated query? you can use after the query this line to check `echo $this->db->last_query(); die;`

Answer (score 0):

i use this code

```
$this->db->select("
              users.*,GROUP_CONCAT(category.title SEPARATOR ',')            
              as title FROM users LEFT JOIN 
                        (procducts as pr INNER JOIN category ON                          
                             pr.category_id =category.id) 
                        ON (users.id=pr.user_id)");


$this->db->group_by("users.id");
```

and this code it's ok,and without any problem .