# Convert SQL JOIN Query to SQL Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter, and I want to convert the SQL query into the Codeigniter-style query

My query looks like this :

```
SELECT tbl_detail_order.ID, tbl_detail_order.order_id, tbl_detail_order.produk, products.name, tbl_detail_order.qty, tbl_detail_order.harga, tbl_order.tanggal, tbl_pelanggan.nama, tbl_pelanggan.alamat, tbl_pelanggan.telp

FROM tbl_pelanggan 
    INNER JOIN (tbl_order INNER JOIN 
                             (products INNER JOIN tbl_detail_order 
                                       ON products.kd_barang = tbl_detail_order.produk) 
                          ON tbl_order.ID = tbl_detail_order.order_id) 
    ON tbl_pelanggan.ID = tbl_order.pelanggan;
```

And I try to make it in Codeigniter like this

```
 public function getAllJoin()
{
  $this->db->select('tbl_detail_order.ID, tbl_detail_order.order_id, tbl_detail_order.produk, products.name, tbl_detail_order.qty, tbl_detail_order.harga, tbl_order.tanggal, tbl_pelanggan.nama, tbl_pelanggan.alamat, tbl_pelanggan.telp');
  $this->db->from('tbl_detail_order');
  $this->db->join('tbl_order','tbl_detail_order.order_id = tbl_order.id','INNER');      
  $this->db->join('tbl_pelanggan','tbl_order.pelanggan = tbl_pelanggan.id','INNER');
  $this->db->join('products','products.kd_barang = tbl_pelanggan.id','INNER');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Can you correct my code? Is it wrong or right?

Comment: Did you bother to test your new version versus the old raw version?  You didn't offer us any sample db data, so we can't really test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this [other post mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534782/nested-joins-in-codeigniter), there isn't an API for nested joins in the CodeIgniter DB syntax. So you just use the outer one, and move the rest inline with that.

```
public function getAllJoin()
{
  $this->db->select('tbl_detail_order.ID, tbl_detail_order.order_id, tbl_detail_order.produk, products.name, tbl_detail_order.qty, tbl_detail_order.harga, tbl_order.tanggal, tbl_pelanggan.nama, tbl_pelanggan.alamat, tbl_pelanggan.telp');
  $this->db->from('tbl_detail_order');
  $this->db->join('tbl_order INNER JOIN (products INNER JOIN tbl_detail_order ON products.kd_barang = tbl_detail_order.produk) ON tbl_order.ID = tbl_detail_order.order_id','tbl_detail_order.order_id = tbl_order.id','INNER');      
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```