# How can I make these two queries a single query with an inner join?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have these two queries that I need to make into a single query.  Keyfield1 and TPOLNO should be the join fields.  How would I go about making this a single query?

```
SELECT TPOLNO, SUM(TTSAMT) AS SUM FROM PFPOSTR410 WHERE 
((TTRNYY=2012 AND TTRNMM=3 AND TTRNDD>=27) OR (TTRNYY=2012 AND TTRNMM>3) OR 
(TTRNYY=2013 AND TTRNMM<=2) OR (TTRNYY=2013 AND TTRNMM=3 AND TTRNDD<=27)) 
GROUP BY TPOLNO HAVING SUM(TTSAMT)>=5000 ORDER BY TPOLNO ASC

SELECT KEYFIELD1, KEYFROBJ FROM CMRELATN WHERE RELROLETC=8
```

Thanks in advance for any direction!

- Josh

Comment: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: I will try to remember that!

Comment: @Denis - best piece of advice I've gotten in a while...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand your questions, you need to do a simple inner join of the 2 tables:

```
SELECT TPOLNO, SUM(TTSAMT) AS SUM, KEYFIELD1, KEYFROBJ
FROM PFPOSTR410, CMRELATN 
WHERE 
    ((TTRNYY=2012 AND TTRNMM=3 AND TTRNDD>=27) OR (TTRNYY=2012 AND TTRNMM>3) OR 
(TTRNYY=2013 AND TTRNMM<=2) OR (TTRNYY=2013 AND TTRNMM=3 AND TTRNDD<=27))
    AND KEYFIELD1=TPOLNO
    AND RELROLETC=8
GROUP BY TPOLNO, KEYFIELD1, KEYFROBJ
HAVING SUM(TTSAMT)>=5000
ORDER BY TPOLNO ASC
```

Comment: yup that is what I needed pretty much.  I edited the statement to remove the KEYFIELD1 from the select clause and added it to the group by clause.  Works like a charm!  Thank you!

Comment: Never sugest using implicit joins, they are a SQL antipattern.

Comment: And group by shoudl always include all the nonaggregate fields even though mysql allows you to do the wrong thing like this.  In general this is a very poor answer using two SQL antipattern techniques. We are not supposed to be teaching the wrong way to do things.

Comment: You are right, i updated my answer to include the rest of the fields in the group by.

Comment: What do you mean "SQL antipattent"?

Comment: @HLGEM - edited the above post for what I changed it to be (now using an inner join)

Comment: @gtsouk - read this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346659/what-are-the-most-common-sql-anti-patterns  It might help a bit.

Comment: @ResourceReaper this question is "closed as not constructive". The answer about explicit vs implicit joins got 13 votes and had no reference to support the claim. I wouldn't say it must be avoided just because of that.