# insert into table A, select from table A join B where condition from B, for each record that meets condition in B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert into `table B` for a range of employees from `table A` where the `select` statement for the `insert` is from `table B`.
To restate that; I have created all the records I need in `table B` for one employee (employeeid = 1).  Now I want to `insert` `into table B` similar records for a range of employees in `table A`.

so far I have

```
insert TABLEB as B
(EMPLOYEEID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
     SELECT A.EMPLOYEEID, B.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2, B.COLUMN3 
     FROM TABLEB 
     WHERE EMPLOYEEID = 1
```

now I want that to insert for each row in `Table A` that meets a selecion criteria

the above works for one employee.  How do I make it iterate for a range of employees from `table A`.
note that the EMPLOYEEID I want to insert for each row in `table B` will be the ID from the employee in `table A.`

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by range?? Can u specify limits of the range from where to where?

Comment: You're missing a join condition between a and b I think. Can you post the schema for table a and b in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
insert TABLEB as B (EMPLOYEEID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) 
SELECT A.EMPLOYEEID, A.COLUMN1, A.COLUMN2, A.COLUMN3 
FROM TABLEA 
WHERE A.EMPLOYEEID between 1 and 13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLEB (EMPLOYEEID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3)
SELECT B.EMPLOYEEID, A.COLUMN1, A.COLUMN2, A.COLUMN3 
FROM TABLEB As B
JOIN TABLEA AS A ON(A.EMPLOYEEID=B.EMPLOYEEID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @loopVar int
Set @loopVar = (select min(employeeid) from mast.employee as e 
                where e.JobTitle = 'Night Cook')

while @loopVar is not null

begin

insert mast.PayProfile
(EmployeeID, PayitemCode, PayItem, EarningId, AllowanceId, 
 Quantity, Rate, Amount, BaseRate, ApplySalarySacrifice)
(select @loopvar, PayitemCode, PayItem, EarningId, AllowanceId, 
 Quantity, Rate, Amount, BaseRate, ApplySalarySacrifice 
 from mast.payprofile as pp
 join mast.Employee as e on e.EmployeeId = pp.EmployeeId 
 where pp.EmployeeId = 224 
 and (earningid is not null or allowanceid is not null))

Set @loopVar = (select min(employeeid) from mast.Employee 
                where EmployeeId>@loopVar and JobTitle='Night Cook' 
                and IsTerminated = 0)
end
```

**Note:** The loop idea was copied from [What are the most common SQL anti-patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346659/what-are-the-most-common-sql-anti-patterns#346679) and modified (because I think there was a typo in the answer).