# parsable sql anti-patterns

Tags: sql, parsing, anti-patterns

I am working on an SQL script-inspecting software. Do you know about any SQL anti-patterns that can be possibly parsed automatically? False positives are okay.

Comment: This question seems too broad as it is. 

You can even find lots of anti-patterns here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346659/what-are-the-most-common-sql-anti-patterns#346679

Comment: @Acapulco Sorry I didn't realize there is no right answer to the question. Thank you for the link, of course I have checked it.

Comment: No worries. StackOverflow is much more helpful (and you'll make it easier for people to help you out) if there's a concrete issue you are asking about. For example, you could try to parse an anti-pattern you found and if you get an error, you can ask for help on that specific error.

Answer (score 0):

this [book](https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) could give you tons of ideas